# Not able to discover term in elasticsearch through kibana but curl request is working fine

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I had some data already residing in ElasticSearch. I added a term {"oncall" :"true"} to some document based on some conditions by python post requests.When I am going to Kibana and trying to search it on discover page. I am not getting any results. But when I am doing following curl request I am getting the results.

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/logstash*/logs/_search?pretty" -d '
{
"query" : {
    "term" : {"oncall" :"true"}
}
}'
```

results

```
"hits" : {
 "total" : 47,
"max_score" : 12.706658,
"hits" : [ {
  "_index" : "logstash-2015.10.20",
  "_type" : "logs",
 .......
.......
```

I want to ask that why i am not able to see the results in kibana and what setting do i need to change.
the query which I am writing on discover-page text box is

```
oncall:true     #this is giving me no results
```

Comment: What occurs if you use your JSON query (`{"term":{"oncall" :"true"}}`) as a one liner in the Kibana text field?

Comment: when I use JSON query as suggested by you in one liner , I am again not getting any results i.e. "No results found "